Voltage (34V AC) between Mac mini M4 chassis and ground
I've got a Mac mini M4 and felt voltage on the chassis, so I measured it with a mulitmeter. It turns out that I get up to 34V AC between the chassis and ground. I did this test with a plugged in MacBook Pro as well, then I got more than 60V AC.
Why is that, is that a normal behaviour?

It could be the use of a "Y capacitor" - see the answer SMPS gives "electric shock"

Classic Y-capacitor leakage!

Have you tried measuring the current that flows?

@Andyaka Yes, I did. No current measurable.

@ChesterGillon That is interesting, thank you both. The more recent Meanwell PSUs such as NGE18I24-P1J are all medical grade as far as I know, so I am a bit surprised that the internal Apple PSU seems to be not.

@Tintenfisch - Hi, As commented, similar questions have been raised before. Searching isn't easy as the phenomenon gets described in different ways (e.g. tingle, shock, vibration or, as in your question, by the voltage being measured). I've closed this as a duplicate of one of the better explanations I found. If site members find other good-quality previous questions, we can add those to the list of duplicates.

@SamGibson You're right! Thanks for pointing out that searching isn't easy for this phenomenon. I did in fact search before, but didn't find an explanation.

@Tintenfisch There's not enough info to answer the exact mechanism for having e.g. 60VAC on computer case. For example, if you live in a 120VAC country, and your desktop computer has three-prong inlet that needs earth/ground, but your wall socket or adapter cable omits it, then 60VAC is what you will have between metal case and earth. There are other mechanisms as well that relate to power inlets being only two-prong. I think two prong devices that are poorly made and exhibit voltage should be banned by law, because hot-plugging them may cause damage to e.g. USB ports so they don't work.
